# Text is getting overlapped or truncated in the saved PDF when I save it from SSRS report

Tags: c#

If the text length(ex:more than 50 char) is more then the text is truncating in the saved PDF file but in the SSRS report the text is showing without truncating.
How to show complete text in PDF without truncating?

Answer (score 0):

if wrapping to next page is no issue for you on the ssrs you can make the column width wide enough you like. I would start with eye guage; but if your end users are going to be printing the pdf. You may want to look at the format of render and doing some test saves with data.